# MixItUp adds 'failed' class to div and does not filter items

Tags: jquery, css, mixitup

I'm trying to use [MixItUp](https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup) to filter grid items. It says it should be pretty simple. Add the class `mix` and another class for the category of the item, and then add the buttons with the same category.

```
<!-- The buttons -->
<button class="filter" data-filter="social">Email</button>
<button class="filter" data-filter="games">Games</button>
<button class="filter" data-filter="merch">Merchandise</button>

<!-- The grid -->
<div class="portfolio-grid" id="MixItUpBCE8F4">
   <div class="portfolio-item mix merch"></div>
   <div class="portfolio-item mix social"></div>
   <div class="portfolio-item mix games"></div>
</div>
```

I have initialised the plugin as such:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function(){
        $('.portfolio-grid').mixItUp();
    });
});
```

And have added the described 'vital' CSS:

```
.portfolio-grid .mix{display: none;}
```

The plugin initialises, and the CSS applies.

However, clicking any of the buttons simply causes the grid items to fade out. And no items show up on the page.

### [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/hq2j17yp/1/)

What have I done wrong? I've followed the docs to the letter.

It seems to me that it's not matching any items. But I can't understand, because as you can see from the code above there are definitely matches as each item definitely has a class that matches one of the `data-filter`s?

Answer (score 2):

But you haven't followed the docs...The docs explain that your `data-filter` attributes on your controls need to be actual selectors, such as classes with leading dots `.` (which is odd, I admit). For example, `data-filter="social"` should be `data-filter=".social"`:

```js
jQuery('.portfolio-grid').mixItUp();
```

```css
.portfolio-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}
.portfolio-item:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}
.portfolio-item:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.mixitup/latest/jquery.mixitup.min.js?v=2.1.2"></script>

<!-- The buttons -->
<button class="filter" data-filter=".social">Email</button>
<button class="filter" data-filter=".games">Games</button>
<button class="filter" data-filter=".merch">Merchandise</button>

<!-- The grid -->
<div class="portfolio-grid" id="MixItUpBCE8F4">
   <div class="portfolio-item mix merch"></div>
   <div class="portfolio-item mix social"></div>
   <div class="portfolio-item mix games"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mat-visual, I think the logic behind it is that you can use any selector (not just classes). For example, if you wanted to target a specific ID, the `data-filter` would be `"#some-id"`

Comment: Yea, I guess that makes sense. Feels sort of icky though :P